# Calculate weighted average per product

Tags: ms-access

I have a question related to [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) calculations. So to be clear, i uploaded the *Excel* table, where i did the calculations. I'm interested in weighted average value, basically how to do the calculation i did in excel in access.

My formula in excel looked like that: `=SUMIFS($I:$I;$G:$G;G2;$H:$H;H2;$B:$B;B2;$C:$C;C2)/SUMIFS($F:$F;$G:$G;G2;$H:$H;H2;$B:$B;B2;$C:$C;C2)`
I get the right sales and sold volume numbers for each code (product), for each group, for each month, for each year.

I have the same database in excel, i got all the additional calculated fields with revenue, month and year values as in excel. However I have to idea how to reproduce my excel formula in access.

The weighted per product on the picture contains the mentioned above formula. I need to find a way to include this calculation in access, where the data is the same.

```
Code    Group      Price per t  Volume  MONTH YEAR  Revenue          Weighted 
13753   avangard   12 818,84    108,85  1     2008   1 395 330,73    13 826,51   
13755   super      11 488,83    26,76   1     2008   307 441,09      15 726,96   
14899   super      11 607,86    64,39   1     2008   747 430,11      15 591,86   
13747   super      11 892,57    62,96   1     2008   748 756,21      16 199,30   
13753   avangard   18 134,69    94,65   1     2008   1 716 448,41    13 826,51
```

How it should be calculated =SUMIFS(Revenue;CriteriaRange(1)=Month;Criteria(1)=Row2(Month);CriteriaRange(2)=Year;Criteria(2)=Row2(Year);CriteriaRange(3)=Code;Criteria(3)=Row2(Code))/SUMIFS(Volume;CriteriaRange(1)=Month;Criteria(1)=Row2(Month);CriteriaRange(2)=Year;Criteria(2)=Row2(Year);CriteriaRange(3)=Code;Criteria(3)=Row2(Code))

If if we separate ourselves from calculated weighted in table sample, based only on provided data the weighted price for item 13753 = (1 395 330,73 + 1 716 448,41)/(108,85 + 94,65) =  15 291,30

@Darren Bartrup-Cook. Found the solution I needed. Thank you very much for helping. This is the end SQL code i used to mirror the SUMIFS function.

```
SELECT Data.Code,  
             Справочник_групп_продукции.Group, 
             Month([Dated]) AS LMonth, 
             Year([Dated]) AS LYear, 
             SUM([Price per t] * [Volume])/SUM([Volume]) AS Wght_Avg
FROM Справочник_групп_продукции INNER JOIN Data ON Справочник_групп_продукции.[Code] = Data.[Code]
GROUP BY Data.Code, 
                   Month([Dated]), 
                   Year([Dated]), 
                   Справочник_групп_продукции.Group;
```

[https://imgur.com/DyMYnEC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8F6W.jpg)

Comment: You tagged with Access and it sounds like you need help with a query.  If so, then you need to show us sample input data in tabular form, along with the expected output.

Comment: I have attached files with data both in access and excel together with anticipated result in excel tables in most-right column (weighted). I have no idea how it should done, via access formulas or a query. I'm a noob in access.

Comment: Note that you should refrain from sharing files whenever possible, especially using shady file sharing services that build in delays and show ads. See [how to share tables on SO for ms Access](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359195/share-a-table-on-stack-overflow-for-easy-import-into-ms-access). This is a site for professional and enthousiast programmers, some programming knowledge on the subject you're posting on is expected.

Comment: I uploaded the picture with sample data instead. It's same for access.

Comment: Have you read my link? We can't import a picture.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I tried my best, hope this table will be useful.

Comment: Ah, the format is usable, but I still don't fully understand what you're asking. Based on the data you've provided, I can't deduce how you're calculating that weighted average. Try to separate sample input data and expected output based on that sample data, like Tim Biegeleisen said, and make sure that if the calculations work, you can get the expected output by only using the sample input.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth the sample input data is all before column Revenue. The revenue is calculated as Price * Volume. F.e. To calculate weighted for first item (code 13753) i summed up revenue by following criterias:1st - MONTH 1, 2nd - YEAR 2008, 3rd - CODE 13753. So what i got is the amount of revenue by item 13753 in January in 2008 and divided by the amount of volume by the exact same criteria. Also to add, there are tons of rows with data, so i just copied few top rows to provide the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

With your table set up as the example table (sorry, can't see the picture) and 
the table name as `MyTable` you just need to perform the sum (*revenue/volume*) and group by the code, month and year.

```
SELECT      Code
            , Group
            , lMonth
            , lYear
            , ROUND(SUM(Revenue)/SUM(Volume),2) AS Weighted_Avg
FROM        MyTable
GROUP BY    Code
            , Group
            , lMonth
            , lYear
```

**NB:**  I've updated the name of the `Month` and `Year` fields to `lMonth` and `lYear` to avoid reserved word conflicts.
I'd probably change my design to use real dates rather than month and year numbers though.

**NB 2:** I'd also move the `Group` to another table using `Code` as a *Primary Key* in that table and a *Foreign Key* in the main table.  This will eliminate any misspelling in the Group name.
The new query would be:

```
SELECT      MyTable.Code
            , Group
            , lMonth
            , lYear
            , ROUND(SUM(Revenue)/SUM(Volume),2) AS Weighted_Avg
FROM        MyTable LEFT JOIN GroupTable ON MyTable.Code = GroupTable.Code
GROUP BY    MyTable.Code
            , Group
            , lMonth
            , lYear
```

**Edit:**

Looking at the SQL you've posted this updated SQL should work:

```
SELECT      Format(Dated,"mmm-yyyy") AS Month_Year
            , Group
            , Data.Code
            , [Price per t]*volume AS Revenue
            , ROUND(SUM([Price per t]*[Volume])/SUM(Volume),2) AS Weighted_Avg
FROM        Справочник_групп_продукции INNER JOIN Data ON Справочник_групп_продукции.Code = Data.Code
GROUP BY    Format(Dated,"mmm-yyyy")
            , Group
            , Data.Code
            , [Price per t]*volume
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although could you provide pls some explanations. What would be the way to handle month/year calculations based on date (field called "dated" in my table)? I have the dates. Also could you explain me pls, how can I adapt your code to my query, because I use query to lookup groups from other table. I have the following code, however it returns me an error. I updated my main post with code.

Comment: I think your error is coming from the weighted average.  Your Revenue is calculated as `[Price per t]*[Volume] AS Revenue`  you can't refer to this as `Revenue` in your weighted average calculation.  Use `ROUND(SUM([Price per t]*[Volume])/SUM(Volume),2) AS Weighted_Avg`.  Your dates can be displayed with `Format(dDate,"mmm-yyyy") AS Month_Year` - you'll need to group this as well.  You can then limit to January 2008 by using `WHERE dDate BETWEEN #2008/01/01# AND #2008/02/01#-1`

Comment: Also you can't show `Price per t` or `volume` in your query as it changes - it's 12 818,84 and 18 134,69 for code 13753 which won't group together.  Also in your SQL you've got a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of your FROM clause - if you use it it should go at the end of the query.